# Send email compared with values from the table

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I try to run this script but it's don't sent any email to useremail. When user select 1,2,3 and summit this script will compare values in sheet(column 10) and sent difference email body. follow This script

```js
function mutisendemail(e) {
if (e.values[10] == "1") {
    var useremail = "test@gmail.com";
    var subject = "test1";
    var body = "number 1 ";
    var photo = DriveApp.getFilesByName('test1.jpg');
    MailApp.sendEmail({
        to: userEmail,
        subject: subject,
        body: body,
        attachments: [photo.next()]
    });
}
if (e.values[10] == "2") {
    var useremail = "test@gmail.com";
    var subject = "test2";
    var body = "number2";
    var photo = DriveApp.getFilesByName('test1.jpg');
    MailApp.sendEmail({
        to: userEmail,
        subject: subject,
        body: body,
        attachments: [photo.next()]
    });
}
if (e.values[10] == "3") {
    var useremail = "test@gmail.com";
    var subject = "test3";
    var body = "number3";
    var photo = DriveApp.getFilesByName('test1.jpg');
    MailApp.sendEmail({
        to: userEmail,
        subject: subject,
        body: body,
        attachments: [photo.next()]
    });
}
}
```

Comment: please make the code readable - [this](http://jsbeautifier.org/) is an online resource you can use to indent your code properly

Comment: what errors are shown in developer tools console

Comment: it's show TypeError: Cannot read property "values" from undefined. (line 2, file "test")

Comment: How is multisendemail being called

Answer (score 1):

Please note that the variable `useremail` and `userEmail` are written different. When I fixed that I've received the e-mail in my Inbox. 
This is full code:

```
function sendSimpleEmail(mynumber){
  var useremail = "myemail@gmail.com";
  var subject = "test"+mynumber;
  var body = "number "+mynumber;
  var photo = DriveApp.getFilesByName('MyFile.pdf'); 

  MailApp.sendEmail({
    to: useremail,
    subject: subject,
    body: body,
    attachments: [photo.next()]
  });
}  

function sendConditionalEmail(){
  var mySheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var myCell = 'B5';
  var cellValue = mySheet.getRange(myCell).getValue();
  if(cellValue=="1"){
    sendSimpleEmail("1");
  }
  else if(cellValue=="2"){
   sendSimpleEmail("2");
  }
  else if(cellValue=="3"){
   sendSimpleEmail("3");
  }
```

Comment: thank u  but it's still don't work.  thank for you comment